# eventlistener fires when I add it in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What I am attempting to do is add and remove textboxes from a table when they are/are not needed. The function needs to execute when a user types into a textbox. The page loads with several textboxes that have this function as an even listener.
The code has been giving me trouble so I put a break point (GC developer tool) at the beginning of the function and typed in a textbox. What happens is on the line:

```
 input.addEventListener("keypress", updateTextBox(TableName, input.id));
```

execution returns to the beginning of the of the function!?

```
 function updateTextBox(TableName, element) {
                var numCells = document.getElementById(TableName).rows.length - 1;
                var lastTxt = document.getElementById(TableName + numCells);
                var curNum = element.id.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
                if (curNum != numCells && element.text == "" && lastTxt.text == "") {
                    document.getElementById(TableName).deleteRow(numCells);
                }
                else if (element.text != "" && lastTxt.text != "") {
                    var input = document.createElement("input");
                    input.type = "text";
                    nextNum = numCells + 2;
                    input.id = TableName + nextNum;
                    input.addEventListener("keypress", updateTextBox(TableName, input.id));
                    newRow = document.getElementById(TableName).insertRow();
                    newCell = newRow.insertCell();
                    newCell.appendChild(input);
                }            
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the function, so it gets called. Instead wrap it in an anonymous function.

```
input.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
    updateTextBox(TableName, input.id));
});
```

Comment: sweet, thanks a lot. Could you explain why this works?

Comment: @bob first you're calling the function with `()` but now you're just passing a function to it. Don't forget to mark it as answer if it helped :)

Comment: wait, the even handler does not seem to be added?

Comment: im sorry, it has been added. Thanks so much.